# ¿Se puede crear un div flexible en altura?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Me gustaría crear un div que al ensanchar la página del navegador, creciera al igual que lo hace una imagen con `width: 100%; height:auto;`

¿Hay alguna forma a día de hoy de hacerlo?

Mi intención sería crear un div con una relación de aspecto 16:9 que aumentase en altura y anchura a medida que ensancho la página.

Comment: Hola Pablo. Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Si se puede pero **lo importante** es que muestres lo que has intentado. Sobre eso te podemos ayudar a mejorar y arreglar tu codigo y asi aprendes más que si te lo damos hecho. Mira [ask] y[mcve] para mejorar la pregunta. Un saludo

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hay un truquito que te permite hacerlo muy fácilmente: cuando el `padding` lo defines con valores porcentuales, el valor de referencia es el ancho del contenedor. De [la web de la W3C, en la página de especificaciones CSS 2](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/box.html#padding-properties):

> The percentage is calculated with respect to the width of the
>   generated box's containing block, even for 'padding-top' and
>   'padding-bottom'. If the containing block's width depends on this
>   element, then the resulting layout is undefined in CSS 2.2.

Traducción y negritas mías: El porcentaje se calcula respecto al **ancho** de la *caja* generada por el bloque contenedor, **incluso en los valores verticales** (padding-top y padding bottom). Si el ancho del bloque contenedor depende de este elemento, entonces el resultado es indefinido.

```css
.ratio16-9 {
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* resultado de 9/16 */
  background-color:gold;
}
#contenedor {

  width:30%;
  background-color: gray;
  margin: 5px;
  position:relative;
}
#main {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="contenedor">
  <div class="ratio16-9"></div>
  <div id="main">hola, este <pre>div</pre> es el contenedor interno
</div>
```

Ahora bien, el div 16/9 tiene un padding que ocupa todo el alto, el contenido en sí mismo tiene una altura de 0 pixels... con lo que si metemos algo ocupará algo de espacio y deformará el div. La solución es que todo lo que esté dentro no afecte al tamaño: en lugar de meter nuestro contenido en este div, que lo único que hace es dar forma y tamaño, lo metemos en otro elemento que tiene posición absoluta.

**Nota**: Opino que la solución correcta se va a basar en el uso de la propiedad descrita anteriormente, pero quizá mi ejemplo (prueba de concepto) no sea la más limpia. Pongo esta respuesta como *wiki* para que cualquier pueda añadir una mejor implementación.

---

Para optimizar un poco el código HTML y no tener un `div` vacío también podemos usar los psudoelementos `::after` o `::before`. Por otra parte, al tener el contenido en un `div` con posición absoluta si sobrepasa el tamaño del contenedor quedará fuera de éste, para evitarlo ponemos un `overflow: auto;` que nos muestre un *scroll* cuando sea necesario.

```css
    #contenedor {
      width: 40%;
      background-color: gold;
      margin: 5px;
      position: relative;
      overflow: auto;
    }

    #contenedor::after {
      content: "";
      display: block;
      padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    }

    #main {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
    }
```

```html
<div id="contenedor">
  <div id="main">Facilis quaerat et id est aut voluptates laboriosam velit. Saepe dignissimos aut impedit sit molestiae aut quibusdam. Earum quis ratione vitae quae sit assumenda officiis dolorem. Nesciunt labore nobis porro consectetur ut.</div>
</div>Facilis quaerat et id est aut voluptates laboriosam velit. Saepe dignissimos aut impedit sit molestiae aut quibusdam. Earum quis ratione vitae quae sit assumenda officiis dolorem. Nesciunt labore nobis porro consectetur ut.
```

Comment: El ejemplo que has actualizado es mejor porque soluciona el problema del alto. Pienso que sería mejor si el main estuviera dentro de ratio16-9, de eso modo tendrías todo contenido en un `div` autónomo, en lugar de tener que tener dos `div` (algo como [esto](https://jsfiddle.net/alvaromontoro/hx5d4s1m/))